# Looking for a stable pawn structure after 1. Nf3

Tags: opening

Question here regarding black responses to Nf3 - at my level 60% of players open with e4, 30% open with d4. The other 10% of the time, it's Nf3.

My issue with Nf3 is that it has the possibility to transpose into many different openings, most of which I am not prepared for. What is the response that allows white the fewest transpositional possibilities?

Comment: That would depend on your defense vs. 1.d4.

Comment: The formation c6-d5-e6 is quite stable, and White basically has two options: play with d4, creating some kind of (Semi)-Slav, and without d4 (often with g3) which gives an English-type opening.

Comment: And also on your defence against 1.e4 -- if you play the Sicilian, then 1.Nf3 c5 is an option.

Comment: 1...f5 almost guarantees a Dutch Defence

Comment: ...Nf6 is relatively noncommital. The knight is probably going there anyway. I don't know if it's worthwhile to stop White from transposing too much, because the quieter he plays, the less chances he has to attack. ...f5 e4!? is really sharp, and I'd be more scared of that than transpositions. If you're a king's indian player (or King's Indian Attack as White,) you can set that formation up easily and don't have to worry about the Samisch and 4 pawns attacks either.

But yes, as overtheboard says, your repertoire as black afects this.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest something like a Sicilian Dragon / Sniper attack with moves like c5, g6, Bg7 etc. White will find it very difficult to stop you playing like this after opening with Nf3 and you don't have to worry about learning a boatload of white transpositional possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I answer 1.Nf3 with 1...e6 followed by 2...f5 and going for the solid Dutch Stonewall or other Dutch. If 2.e4 I go for 2...d5 and go for a Fort Knox French variation. Super solid systems.